# How to burn an ISO-image with root access only?

Tags: permissions, iso, burning, disk-utility, brasero

I would like to know how can I burn an ISO-image file in a directory (inside another partition) that I can only read with root permission using sudo. There is no left room, I cannot copy, move or duplicate the file. I cannot change the owner nor the permissions either.

If I launch Brasero as root `gksu brasero`, from there I can read the directory and select the ISO file but I cannot select the blank CD to burn it.

If I run disk utility from the menus, then I can use the CD/DVD but I cannot read the directory to select the ISO file. I cannot find how to boot from the command line the Disk Utility. Disk Utility is a useful program without which many things cannot be done or is very problematic to do them, for example if you want to mount the partition where the persistent file (for an ISO booting) lives. Why isn't it with other programs/utilities??

Is there a way (maybe with command line) to read with sudo the file and pass the data to a program that burns the disk without buffering problems?

Also, I would like to know if there is a labyrinthine solution to this and if that is normal or the applications are not well user-designed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bindfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bindfs) [image: Install bindfs] to create another view of a filesystem with different permissions. Create a view of that directory that gives you the permission to read the file. For example, the following command creates a view of `/media/sda1/private` on `/mnt` where every user can read every file:

```
sudo bindfs -p a+rX /media/sda1/private /mnt
```

The following command creates a view of `/media/sda1/private` on `/mnt` where the user `robert` is the owner of every file (and has the associated permissions):

```
sudo bindfs -u robert /media/sda1/private /mnt
```

To remove the view, unmount it (`sudo umount /mnt`).

Comment: Sounds great and simple, Gilles; looks like a like a powerful tool. I'll try it, but I am sure it will work. I was trying to `sudo chown` in the mounted  filesystem hoping that chown would be logical only but no way if the mount is read-only. Thank you.